# Possible PHP/Javascript Race Condition

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, race-condition

I'm relatively new to web programming.  New to Javascript, PHP, Ajax, etc.  I have been searching Google to a seemingly simple solution to this problem for a while now, but have given up.  I believe there is a race condition happening, but everything related to race conditions and PHP and Javascript seem to have a case-by-case solution.

Here's the setup:
I have a PHP page that outputs a table.  In one of the rows in one of the tables, I fill a cell with an additional table.  It has 5 cells, and I would like to change the colors of the cells to reflect the signal strength of wifi cards on a machine (there are currently only two cards). So after a table has been filled and the id's of the cells have been set, I call a javascript function that posts another piece of PHP code to cat /proc/net/wireless, parse and return the signal strength of the card I have called.

The problem:
The javascript and PHP code that parses the wireless cards, gets the cell ID's and set the colors works fine for one card.  However, when I call the Javascript function from within a  tag in PHP, only the last call does anything.  The first seems to do nothing.

I'm completely stumped, and have exhausted all my Google search terms...

PHP code:

```
<?php include('assets/header.inc.php'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo _JS_?>/ajax_home_display.js"></script>
<div id="cm_body" onload="return false">
    <?php
        $ap_intf = rtrim(shell_exec("cat /tmp/config | grep AP_DEV | cut -d'=' -f2"));
        $mesh_intf = rtrim(shell_exec("cat /tmp/config | grep MESH_DEV | cut -d'=' -f2"));
        $uptime = rtrim(shell_exec("uptime | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d',' -f1"));

    function display_status_intf($intf, $name) 
    {   
        global $uptime;
        $packet_success = "100%";

        echo "
        <tr>
        <td style=\"font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;\"><pre>$intf [$name]</pre></td>
        <td id=\"sig_status_$intf\">
        <table id=\"intf_status\" class = \"list\" cellpadding=10>
        <td id=\"sig_st_1_$intf\"></td>
        <td id=\"sig_st_2_$intf\"></td>
        <td id=\"sig_st_3_$intf\"></td>
        <td id=\"sig_st_4_$intf\"></td>
        <td id=\"sig_st_5_$intf\"></td>
        </table>
        <td><pre>$uptime</pre></td></td>
        <td style=\"text-align:center;\"><pre id=\"packet_success_$intf\">$packet_success</pre></td>
        </tr>
        <script>update_interface('$intf')</script>
        ";

    }   

        // Make a table
        echo "<table class=\"list\" cellpadding=1>";
        echo "<tr><th>Interface</th><th>Signal Status</th><th>Uptime</th><th>Packet success</th></tr>";
            // Make a row on the table for the first wifi card (wifi0)
            if ($ap_intf)
                display_status_intf($ap_intf, "AP");

        // Add a blank row
        echo "<tr><td colspan=\"7\" height=\"30px\"></td></tr>";
            // Make a row on the table for the second wifi card (wifi1)
            if ($mesh_intf)
                display_status_intf($mesh_intf, "Mesh");

        echo "</table>";
    ?>  
</div>
<?php include('assets/footer.inc.php'); ?>
```

Javascript code:

```
    THRESH1 = -60;
    THRESH2 = -55;
    THRESH3 = -50;
    THRESH4 = -45;

    function update_interface(intf)
    {
        xmlhttpPost("run_interface_status.php","intf="+intf,interface_stat_response);
    }

    function interface_stat_response(strQuery,strResponse)
    {
        var sig_st = [];

        // Trim response
        var test_return = strResponse;
        var intface = strQuery.split("=");
        var intf = intface[1];

        // Get cell ID's, put in an array sig_st
        for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
             sig_st[i] = document.getElementById("sig_st_"+i+"_"+intf);
        // Reset all colors to default
        for (i=1;i<=2;i++)
            sig_st[i].setAttribute("style", "background-color:transparent");

        if (test_return != "err") {
            // Set all colors based on the wifi strength
            sig_st[1].setAttribute("style", "background-color:red");

            if (test_return > THRESH1)
                sig_st[2].setAttribute("style", "background-color:orange");
            if (test_return > THRESH2)
                sig_st[3].setAttribute("style", "background-color:yellow");
            if (test_return > THRESH3)
                sig_st[4].setAttribute("style", "background-color:green");
            if (test_return > THRESH4)
                sig_st[5].setAttribute("style", "background-color:green");
        }
    }
```

The Ajax heavy lifting (if it matters)

```
    function xmlhttpPost(strURL,strQuery,responseFunc)
    {
        var xmlHttpReq = false;
        var self = this;
        // Mozilla/Safari
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        // IE
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
        self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
                responseFunc(strQuery,self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
            }
        }
        self.xmlHttpReq.send(strQuery);
    }

    function trim(s)
    {
        s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
        s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
        s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");
        return s;
    }
```

Some additional information:  I believe it to be a race condition since Firebug shows that two posts have been fired, each returning the correct values, but when I place a breakpoint in the beginning of the response function (interface_stat_response()), Firebug only falls in it once with the latter $intf and $strength variables (wifi1's stuff).

Also any general pointers would be great.  I know the code isn't pretty, but I want to get better :3

Comment: don't do this.  It's wrong.  Use jquery, or at LEAST use css classes for your colors.

Comment: do you just want it to work, or do you only want to learn some javascript? because in the first case you'll probably want to try jquery (http://www.jquery.com/), you'll love it. Otherwise we will try to explain anyway :)

Comment: I suspect the 2nd callback is actually being executed, as Firebug will only break once even if a callback is executed twice asynchronously. Try using an alert or console.log within interface_stat_response to see exactly how many times it is called. If the JS always fails in the 2nd response you can make Firebug breakpoints conditional and then ensure you only inspect the second - by which time you should already see the effects of the 1st on screen.

Comment: @deltree could you try and help the OP by explaining why you think it's wrong? Seems to me like using JQuery or CSS classes would make no functional difference here. Also, not everyone has the option of using JQuery - it's not a magic bullet.

Comment: yeah like tomfumb said, adding a quick alert and seeing how many times it pops up is a quick and dirty way to isolate your problem.

Comment: All great responses.  I guess I'll use jQuery, but if the problem is apparent to anyone, I'd sleep like a baby tonight if I could get it to work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing everything, the best I can offer is...

Try replacing your AJAX heavy lifting, with the jQuery post method http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

It will require jQuery but it should be easy enough to try and it might fix it.

jQuery is a very helpful tool in dealing with AJAX/JS in general.

If the problem is in your AJAX heavy lifting, this should fix it.

Comment: JQuery seems to be the path to go, even people I know suggested it right off the bat.  Since I am new (clearly) to web development, I really wanted to do it the hard way first; get my hands dirty.   However, maybe it was a bad idea seeing as I spent so much time on this stupid little application.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're not using [jquery](http://jquery.com/).  Jquery has a beautiful [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method that allows you to update things easier.  The reason I mention it is because I see:

```
document.getElementById("sig_st_"+i+"_"+intf)
```

which is just all around bad practice.  Use [css classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) to identify your different settings and wire them up based on some other value.

I'm assuming you're right about the race condition.  I don't have the ability to test your code at the moment.  If you want to do things without jquery, you will have to make sure your js waits for the php to finish loading.  If you really want to do things this way, which is, as far as I'm concerned, the worst way to do it, you'll need a while loop.  Check for the existence of the elements in a while loop until they exist, then go around and set things.

If you swapped this for a class, instead of coloring by ID, your result will be much simpler and much smoother.

**wasn't going to post this, but people asked for clarification

Comment: Although you're probably right, I have been warming up to web development through steps.  Fist PHP, then Javascript, then Ajax and DOM methods, and haven't gotten around to CSS.

However, I was curious, what's the bad practice you mentioned?  Using document.getElementById, the concatenation of the strings and variables?  I would really like to know, as to avoid future screwups.

Comment: @JustynBell I know you have.  I can see the code that I used to write many years ago.  Trust me.  Use CSS classes.  The first little bit of the language required to do that is so easy to learn you'll be kicking yourself over bits of code like the one I quoted.